# Execute the bash script in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have written a script for bash,and install bash on the Windows 10, so when try to run that script in the command prompt write this syntax:

```
bash -c "/home/behzad/SIP-CMD-BYE_OLT-CMD-ACT.sh 09400098129 1234 8 2
 1 1 99 3 2001"
```

Everything is ok! Now I want to run that script in SQL Server, for this purpose write this T-SQL in SQL Server:

```
EXEC master..xp_CMDShell 'bash -c "/home/behzad/SIP-CMD-BYE_OLT-CMD-ACT.sh 09400098129 1234 8 2 1 1 99 3 2001"'
```

but SQL Server shows just character result `W` and bash script does not work. How can I solve that problem? Thanks all.

Comment: Try running the command from SSMS with the results to text option to see if you get additional messages. I suspect using xp_cmdshell to shell from a windows shell to a Linux shell will be problematic, although you might be able to get it to work with workarounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
-- To allow advanced options to be changed.
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
GO
-- To update the currently configured value for advanced options.
RECONFIGURE
GO
-- To enable the feature.
EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1
GO
-- To update the currently configured value for this feature.
RECONFIGURE
GO
```